# Unable to write to the default's Inno Setup log file from a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, inno-setup

I want to make use of the Inno Setup default log file to log the errors from my PowerShell scripts, but when I try to write on them, it seems to be always in use.

After some research I found that the temporal `SetupName_Version.tmp` is using the file but I'm kind of stuck with it. Maybe is a good idea to create a secondary log file where to log my scripts errors? What I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Script:

```
$LogFile=$args[1]
echo "Second arg is $LogFile"
"Second arg is $LogFile" | out-file $LogFile -append
pause
```

Output:

```
Second arg is C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup Log 2020-06-24 #019.txt
out-file : The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Setup Log 2020-06-24 #019.txt'
because it is being used by another process.
At C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\is-EUMKB.tmp\check_wsl_feature_minimal.ps1:9 char:28
+ "Second arg is $LogFile" | out-file $LogFile -append
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Press Enter to continue...:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log file is opened by the installer. Two programs cannot write the the same file at the same time.

You will have to log to a different file in your PowerShell script. If you want to have all information in one file, you can copy over the PowerShell script log file to the installer log after the script finishes. You can use [`LoadStringsFromFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringsfromfile) and [`Log`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_log) functions.

```pascal
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  Args, PsLogPath: string;
  LogLines: TArrayOfString;
  I: Integer;
begin
  PsLogPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\ps.log');
  Args := '-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "script.ps1" "%s"';
  Args := Format(Args, [PsLogPath]);
  Exec('powershell.exe', Args, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  if not LoadStringsFromFile(PsLogPath, LogLines) then
  begin
    Log('PowerShell log file does not exist or cannot be read');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('PowerShell log:')
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(LogLines) - 1 do
    begin
      Log(LogLines[I]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The log file should be in UTF-8 encoding: `Out-File -Encoding utf8`.

---

Though I would use an output redirection, to capture everything that the PowerShell script produces, including errors/exceptions, rather than the explicit logging with `Out-File`.

```pascal
Args := '/C powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "script.ps1" ' +
        '> "%s" 2>&1';
Args := Format(Args, [PsLogPath]);
Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), Args, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated,
     ResultCode);
```

Yet another option is using [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript).

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again, Martin.